# how to correct hresult error.ms sql server

Tags: sql-server, exception, exists, hresult

when remotely accessing an instance, I try to open 'new query' in the sql server , it is given below error:

Error: already exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030050 (STG_E_FILEALREADYEXISTS))

How to correct this error?

Answer (score 1):

actually, this error stems from a system bug.

When you open a new query, it is defined in the temp file.

The system cannot find the path specified in the temp file because  there is no defined folder in the temp file.

To find the origin of the error,  carry out following steps on the command prompt:

1) type the following:

> echo %temp%

2)it gives the below path which temp files is saved.

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\3

3) when we goes to the specified path to reach the temp file:

> cd C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\3

it gives the error:
The system cannot find the path specified.

Solution: it should be created the specified file in the above path.